# Cleared static and now collect static won't work

Tags: python, django

My static files wouldn't stay updated so I just ran `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear` on my server to clear everything. Now when I run `python manage.py collectstatic` nothing happens. I have tried `service unicorn restart` and `service gninx restart` but still nothing changes. Here is a link to my website so you can what is happening. Obviously I would like it look styled, which it does not.

http://evverest.com

Here is my settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/django/django_project/django_project/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]
```

Comment: What's the value of `STATIC_ROOT` in your settings and does file collects there when you run `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: They collect in my static folder in the project. I see all the Django static files collecting but not my css file that is used for website styles

Comment: What's the value of `STATICFILES_DIRS`?

Comment: Apparently I don’t have a `STATICFILES_DIRS`... although everything was working before I cleared the static files

Comment: Maybe earlier you had `STATICFILES_DIRS` when you ran `collectstatic`. Now to run it again, you need it. So try by adding it.

Comment: What did you get when you run `python manage.py collectstatic` command in server?

Comment: I added an answer because I was able to get it to work... Just not sure if what I did is good practice?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my settings to this and it seems to work. Not sure if this is bad practice though since it isn't what I had before?

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    '/static/',
]
```